# Order Y axis labels based on X increasing values

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2

I have this data like this

```
z <- structure(list(Description = c("Neurotransmitter receptors and postsynaptic signal transmission", 
"Muscle contraction", "Class A/1 (Rhodopsin-like receptors)", 
"Signaling by Rho GTPases", "Metabolism of carbohydrates", "Extracellular matrix organization", 
"Transmission across Chemical Synapses", "G alpha (i) signalling events", 
"GPCR ligand binding", "Neuronal System"), p.adjust = c(0.563732077253957, 
0.563732077253957, 0.774251160588198, 0.797669099976286, 0.655931854998983, 
0.655931854998983, 0.563732077253957, 0.774251160588198, 0.774251160588198, 
0.655931854998983), Count = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 13L)), row.names = c("R-HSA-112314", "R-HSA-397014", 
"R-HSA-373076", "R-HSA-194315", "R-HSA-71387", "R-HSA-1474244", 
"R-HSA-112315", "R-HSA-418594", "R-HSA-500792", "R-HSA-112316"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to plot labels of y axis based on values of x axis, so from the smallest one to the largest one. Now it plots me in alphabetic order. How to do this?

```
ggplot(z, aes(Count, Description, size=Count, color=p.adjust))+
  geom_point()
```

Somethine like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `forcats::fct_reorder(Description, Count)` you can change the order of y values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(z, aes(Count, fct_reorder(Description, Count), size=Count, color=p.adjust))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>